# DocumentClient takes too long when queried over a DateTime field

Tags: c#, datetime, azure-cosmosdb, iso8601

I have the following code to get the list of some objects from a DocumentDB database:

```
var document = this._client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(UriFactory.CreateCollectionUri(dbName, collectionName), queryOptions)
.Where(r => r.pDate >= startDate && r.pDate <= endDate);

var result = document.ToList();
```

`pDate` is of type `DateTime`, and stored in the database as string with ISO8601 format.

The query takes unreasonably too long, like 4 to 5 minutes, to return the results back. When I trace the program it is that `.ToList()` where the program gets stuck. Oddly, the query quickly returns for some specific start and end dates.
The query also quickly comes back with some results if I put the filter on some fields other than `pDate`.

My settings are consistent with explanations in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates) but I still get a very poor performance almost all the time except for those few exceptions.

I have tried several methods mentioned here and there to resolve the issue, but no luck so far. I appreciate any comment or solution to the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest you to save dates as DateTime and see if performance are better

Comment: @MartinoBordin - apparently Azure DocumentDB does *not* natively support `DateTime`... But since it *does* support `Number`, maybe OP can try storing them as epoch values. As described in: [Working with Dates in Azure DocumentDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-azure-documentdb-4/).

Comment: Sorry I misread that @hagh is already using DateTime to QUERY (not STORING, you're right @Corak) the data. Try to add a RangeIndex, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates#indexing-datetimes-for-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the indexing that is applied on this particular field.

From this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies,
you would need an Range index for range or Order by Queries.

The default index policy that is applied to a collection is
"Hash for Strings and Range for Numbers"

Datetimes are stored as strings, so for running range comparison queries or order by queries you would need to set the indexing policy to "Range" for string datatypes with precision to -1.